# Adding Column and Trimming Data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In a view I created, I wish to add a new column. This column is going to be used to display the result of comparing two columns in the view

For example, If column 1 = column 2 then new column = 1 else new column = 0.

How would I go about adding this new column to the view?

Also, I wish to trim the last 3 characters of all the values that are printed out in a said column, how would I go about doing this as well?

Much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to use Case when? could you show me the query

Comment: `alter view` . . .

Comment: I don't understand trimming the last 3 characters of 1 and 0 from a case statement.  but all you're doing is altering the view and adding a comma after the last column of the select and then `case when column1=column2 then 1 else 0 end as NewColumn`  `left` or `substr` may work depending on RDBMS... assuming mysql... to eliminate the last 3 characters, but again last 3 of 1 or 0... seems well odd.  ok `left(colname, len(colname)-3)`

Comment: Sorry, the trimming was from a whole different column, which I just figured out. Now I want to compare two columns in my view. If they match, I want a brand new column to display a 1, if they don't match I want it to display a zero. I under stand how to make a case statement for this but I just dont know how to create the new column to be populated with the 0's and 1's.

Comment: A column in a view is not "populated". A view is really just a `SELECT` statement that is stored somewhere (the statement is stored, not the results).

Answer (score 0):

All you're doing is altering the view and adding a comma after the last column of the select and then entering `case when column1=column2 then 1 else 0 end as NewColumn`

as for trimming last 3 characters of a column...

Here's one way...

```
left(colname, len(colname)-3)
```